# Django 'View' object has no attribute 'attribute'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am new to Django and I cannot figure out why my the model attribute domain_authority cannot be accessed below for the special method `__str__`.

Here is my app `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.site_graph, name='site_graph'),
]
```

And my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Metric(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    domain_authorty = models.FloatField()
    page_authorty = models.FloatField()
    date_queried = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain_authority
```

And my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Site, Metric

def site_graph(request):
    sites = Site.objects.order_by('name')
    metrics = Metric.objects.order_by('site')
    return render(request, 'da/site_graph.html', {'sites': sites, 'metrics': metrics})
```

I am importing `Metric` into `views.py` so why would I be getting the error `'Metric' object has no attribute 'domain_authority'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your definition of the Metric class: "domain_authorty" is missing the "i" in authority.

Comment: So embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: :) I end up with typos like that all the time when I'm not using an IDE.